# Launch AWS EC2 Instance with User-data using the .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

How do I set ECS_CLUSTER=my_cluster_name in user-data when launching a new EC2 instance using the AWS .NET SDK?

I've found info on doing this manually by running a bash script on the machine. But I'm specifically interested in learning how to do this programmatically, using the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in the RunInstancesRequest class. The key for me was not only in finding the UserData field, but also in including the IamInstanceProfile. Here's an example:

```
string userDataString = $"#!/bin/bash \necho ECS_CLUSTER=my_cluster_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config";
string userData = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userDataString));
var response = client.RunInstances(new RunInstancesRequest 
{
    ImageId = "ami-abc12345",
    InstanceType = "t2.micro",
    KeyName = "my-key-pair",
    MaxCount = 1,
    MinCount = 1,
    SecurityGroupIds = new List<string> { "sg-1a2b3c4d"},
    SubnetId = "subnet-6e7f829e",
    UserData = userData,
    IamInstanceProfile = new IamInstanceProfileSpecification { Name = "ecsInstanceRole" }
});
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TRunInstancesRequest.html